# Matlab mex & fortran free compiler

Tags: matlab, compiler-construction, fortran

Have a bunch of mex files for a research project that needs to be compiled in/through Matlab. This, as I have read, should be done via for example Intel Visual Fortran and MS Visual c++. Have downloaded and installed MS SDK 7.1 which contains the last one but for compiling Fortran I can´t find anything available (at least not for free). Anyone have an idea what I should do/know some other Fortran compiler that works?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which release of MATLAB you are using. Supported compilers are listed on the MathWorks web site. The ones for the latest release are at [Supported and Compatible Compilers – Release 2014b](http://uk.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2014b/index.html), with older releases linked from that page on the left-hand side:

[image]